# Issue using Python Azure ServiceBus SDK to send batch of messages with object body

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to pass a list of Messages to Service Bus via the Python SDK and I get a 400 response as JSON is not in required format.

I am doing something like this and it fails:

```
messages = [Message({'id':1,'name':'bob'}),Message({'id':2,'name':'bill'})]
sb.send_queue_message_batch('queue_name', messages)
```

If I do this it works:

```
messages = [Message('bob'),Message('bill')]
sb.send_queue_message_batch('queue_name', messages)
```

Or if I call send_queue_message individually like this it works

```
sb.send_queue_message('queue_name', Message({'id':1,'name':'bob'}))
sb.send_queue_message('queue_name', Message({'id':2,'name':'bill'}))
```

Looking at the source it calls a method on the message to create the format expected in a batch so not sure what I should be doing differently.  Unfortunately all examples of batch I can find are the simple string approach.

The consumer at the other end will be a .Net app so I need to ensure it can still be deserialised.  I could call json.dump on the message content and pass it as a stringified version of the body but that does not sound like the ideal solution.

Thanks

SDK Source for batch: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/587bc9a2f955f43c67b02c537521f31aa4c27555/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/servicebusservice.py#L892

Comment: Could you please post the exception details ?

Comment: The response from the service bus rest endpoint is bad request 400. Json is not in required format. I don't think there is an exception in the SDK that I can see. I think it is something in the serialisation of the messages for batch operations that doesn't seem to work if you pass in an object rather than a string for the message body.

Comment: Just had a another look in the SDK and the call to get the body as required for batch just returns body decoded as utf8 with a comment that it has to be a string. I'll try encoding the message body so the SDK can decode it and see if that works

Comment: This seems to work, although I don't think this should be how to interact with the SDK:

`messages = list(map(lambda x: Message(json.dumps(x)), commands))
self.service_bus.send_queue_message_batch(self.queue_name, messages)`

Answer (score 0):

Yo will be able to send any object using the ServiceBusMessage in v7 of servicebus https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/

```
import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


CONNECTION_STR = os.environ['SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STR']
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ["SERVICE_BUS_QUEUE_NAME"]

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
      sender.send_messages([ServiceBusMessage(object1), ServiceBusMessage(object2)])
```